# How to format time values to "00:00" and "00:00:00" Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a `Long` value named `delta` which contains a time value in milliseconds.

I am trying to format it in a readable `String` like `00:00:00`, or if the hour value is zero `00:00`.

```kotlin
private fun remainingTime(delta: Long): String {

    val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(delta)

    return if (hours == 0L) {
        String.format(
            "%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(delta) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(delta)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(delta) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(delta))
        )
    } else {
        String.format(
            "%02d:%02d:%02d",
            hours,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(delta) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(delta)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(delta) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(delta))
        )
    }
}
```

Above code works, but looks very inefficient. I bet there is a smart Kotlin way to solve this?

Comment: What platform are you targeting? JVM or JS or Native?

Comment: @Sweeper Android Studio .. JVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

private val hhmmss = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")
private val mmss = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss")

private fun remainingTime(delta: Long): String =
    LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(delta / 1000)
        .format(if (delta > 60 * 60 * 1000) hhmmss else mmss)
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise version of the code would be to use the `to*Part()` functions on a `Duration`, e.g.

```
    val duration = java.time.Duration.ofMillis(delta)
    val hours = duration.toHours()
    val minutes = duration.toMinutesPart()
    val seconds = duration.toSecondsPart()

    return if (hours == 0L) {
        String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    } else {
        String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
fun main() {
        
        println(remainingTime(1711642863619))
    }
    private fun Long.formatTheDuration(): String {
        val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(this)
        val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(this) % 60
        val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(this) % 60
    
        return buildString {
            if (hours > 0) {
                append("%02d:".format(hours))
            }
            append("%02d:%02d".format(minutes, seconds))
        }
    }
    
    private fun remainingTime(delta: Long): String {
        return delta.formatDuration()
    }
```